# How to run my informatica workflows using the pmcmd/.ksh?

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to run the workflows using pmcmd or .ksh, but i m facing the error
saying

Failed to authenticate login. [UM_10205] [UM_10205] Failed to authenticate the user [user_name] that belongs to the security domain [e-directory]. For more information, see the domain logs.
Disconnecting from Integration Service.

I have tried logging into informatica and run the workflows thru workflow manager, it is running. I am not able to find the reason why it is saying authentication issue, if it is an authentication issue it should not allow me to login to informatica.

pmcmd startworkflow -sv intg_ser -d Domain_name -usd e-directory -u user  -pv encrypted_passwd -f app_CCMLB_FPERX -wait wf_4100_CCML_CAP_PKG_EXT

Comment: Did you check if the password is encrypted correctly and the encrypt_passwd variable set?

Comment: Hi Samik, Yes i encrypted the passwd using pmpasswd.

Comment: Okay. But you cannot pass the encrypted password directly in the pmcmd command. You have to assign it to a variable and export it, then pass that variable name in the command. Not sure if you are doing it already. Other than that the command looks fine.

Comment: Samik's right. You seem to be passing the password. Instead, you need to pass the name of environmental variable holding the encrypted password.

Comment: Hi Samik, I tried with your suggestion
pmcmd startworkflow -sv intg_ser -d Domain_name -usd e-directory -uv INF_USER -pv INFA_PWD -f app_CCMLB_FPERX -wait wf_4100_CCML_CAP_PKG_EXT. 

I am still getting this error
ERROR: Environmental variable [INF_PWD] is undefined.